# JsHint showing error with es6 object descructuring assignment

Tags: ecmascript-6, jshint

I have the following test code

```
const sth = {
  one: 'one',
  two: 'two',
  three: {
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar',
  }
};

const state = {
  ...sth
};
```

When I run jshint I get the following output

```
jshint --config .jshintrc test.js
test.js: line 12, col 3, Expected '}' to match '{' from line 11 and instead saw '...'.
test.js: line 12, col 6, Missing semicolon.
test.js: line 12, col 9, Missing semicolon.
test.js: line 12, col 6, Unrecoverable syntax error. (92% scanned).

4 errors
```

But this is perfectly valid es6 code.

My .jshintrc looks like the following:

```
{
  "curly": false,
  "expr": true,
  "maxlen": 200,
  "esversion": 6
}
```

Is there a magic setting that I am missing to make this pass?

Comment: did you tried "esversion": 7

Comment: @sabareesh [That will not work](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#esversion). And even if it would, object rest/spread properties is not an ES7 (or better, ES2016) feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using [Object Rest/Spread Properties](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) which is not in ES6 and not even a standard, yet. Currently it is at stage 3.

[JSHint does not support Object Rest/Spread Properties](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/2991), yet. You could replace JSHint with ESLint which has [experimental support using `experimentalObjectRestSpread`](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring).

Or, of course, you could just ignore these lines as sabareesh suggests. Personally, however, I would advise against it. It pollutes the code base and also disables subsequent linting. I would suggest using ESLint instead as it usually has better support for newer features and seems to be more popular anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
 var state =  {
    // jshint ignore:start
    ...sth,
   // jshint ignore:end
  }
```

try these.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a file named .jshintrc in your app's root with the following content:

```
{
    "esversion": 9
}
```

Basically, destructuring is not available before es9.